# Django Createview for generic Model

Tags: python, django, generics, modelform

I've been searching really hard for this, and i can't find it anywhere. So, here it goes:

I'm trying to build an generic class that takes a generic Model as parameter and creates a form for it. For this i'm using Django's ModelForm and CreateView classes. The main goal to this, is when i need to create a new form, i just declare a new URL passing the Model name.

### urls.py

```
url(r'^create', GenericCreate(model=Author).as_view(), name='create'),
```

### views.py

```
class GenericCreate(CreateView):

    def __init__(self, model, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GenericCreate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_class = to_modelform(self.model)
```

to_modelform is a function that i implemented that converts a model to a modelform, and it works.

This gives me the following error:

**AttributeError at /create
This method is available only on the view class.**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not be creating an instance of the view class, `as_view` will do that for you.

You would normally call `ViewClass.as_view()`, not `ViewClass().as_view()`.

Also, `CreateView` already takes `model` as a parameter, so you should define your url as:

`url(r'^create', CreateView.as_view(model=Author), name='create'),`

For a proper look at how this works, have a look at the [`as_view` method on CreateView](http://ccbv.co.uk/CreateView/). *(Full disclosure -- I built `ccbv.co.uk`.)*

Comment: Thanks!! It works now.. i did what you suggested and also had to delete "model" from the __init__ function parameters.

Comment: Glad that worked `:)` If you're satisfied with the answer, please feed my stackoverflow points addiction, and make it the accepted answer! `:P`

Answer (score 2):

meshy has provided the answer, but note that your `to_modelform` function is unnecessary. CreateView works perfectly well with a model or model instance rather than a form, see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms).

Comment: Thank you... I'll read it in more detail. I'm new to python and Django. I deleted my `to_modelform` function and the error `TypeError at /create
'instance' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error as well (`TypeError: 'instance' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`); for me it was related to defining the Model instead of the Form in `form_class`.